# mongodb backup process resume from the point of failure

Tags: mongodb, percona

I need to take full backup of mongodb which has around 1TB. Consider that backup process got failed almost at the end of it and if we start again from starting point it would cost more in terms of money as well as time.

Any ways to handle this situation? I mean, any solutions where I can restart my backup process from the point of failure?

Answer (score 0):

For 1TB data it is faster to do [file system snapshot](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/) ( it take few seconds )

Comment: thanks, but our main objective is not to restart backup process from scratch.